# Using a 'button' I would like to move a row of data on excel to another sheet based on a specific cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to find a macro for a 'button' that will move a row of data based on the Cell (F) Value ='Completed'  I am also having trouble determining my data range, I think that is what is wrong with my macro.  My data starts in cell A2 and I have columns through I (A-I are my columns).  I have inserted the 'Completed' button and go to 'Assign Macro'  Basically, when I click the button, I want the entire row of data to move to the next sheet in the next blank row when the status, Column F, is marked Complete. Can anyone help me with writing the code or point me in the right direction?  Thank you!

I tried inserting a code in "assign macro" for a button. I was expecting that when I click the button the entire row would move to Sheet 2 based on the value of F being marked Completed. When Column F is marked completed, I pushed the button but got a Run-time error '9' subscript out of range. Hi, that's kinda the problem, I haven't been able to write one or find one that works but here is what I did put in

```vb
Sub Remove()

' Remove Macro

    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$AS$65336").AutoFilter Field:=40, 
    Criteria1:="COMPLETED"
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(2, 1).SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Removed Items").Select
    Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Main Sheet").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$2:$AS$65336").AutoFilter Field:=40, 
    Criteria1:="COMPLETED"
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(2, 1).SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Sheets("Removed Items").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Sheets("Main Sheet").Select
    Range("B3").Select
 End Sub
```

Comment: most likely you have a sheet name or workbook name in your code that does not exist in you workbook.  But, without seeing the code we will never be able to help with certainty.

Comment: Hi, that's kinda the problem, I haven't been able to write one or find one that works but here is what I did put in

Comment: We can help you overcome the subscript out of range error, Which is most likely caused by the fact that you have Sheet names hard coded and one of those sheets do not exists as spelled in the code.  But if you want us to rewrite your code, that is too broad for this forum.

Comment: On which line of code do you get the error (it will be highlighted if you press 'Debug' in the error dialog)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it is self-explanatory, you can modify code as you need.

```
Sub Move_Main()
    Const KeyWord = "COMPLETED"
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowSrc As Long, lastRowDest As Long

    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main Sheet")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Removed Items")
    
    lastRowSrc = FindLastRow(wsSrc, "A")
    lastRowDest = FindLastRow(wsDest, "A")
    
    MoveRowsBasedOnStatus wsSrc, wsDest, lastRowSrc, lastRowDest, KeyWord
End Sub

Private Function FindLastRow(ws As Worksheet, col As String) As Long
    FindLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Private Sub MoveRowsBasedOnStatus(wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, lastRowSrc As Long, lastRowDest As Long, status As String)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = lastRowSrc To 2 Step -1
        If wsSrc.Cells(i, 6).Value = status Then
            wsSrc.Rows(i).Cut wsDest.Rows(lastRowDest + 1)
            wsSrc.Rows(i).Delete
            lastRowDest = lastRowDest + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```